# accounts is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

in this django tutorial, we are creating a blogsite, at this pont we are creating a login form for users, unfortunately im getting and error saying that "accounts" is not a registered namespace, how do i fix this?

my urls.py file for the app "accounts":

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from.import views

 appname= 'accounts'


 urlpatterns=[
   url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_view, name= "signup"),
   url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name = "login" ),
```

]

my views.py for the app:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm



 def signup_view(request):
     if request.method== 'POST':
        form= UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
        #log the user in

        return redirect('narticle:list')
    else:
      form=UserCreationForm()
    return render (request,'accounts/accounts_signup.html', {'form': form})

   def login_view(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(data= request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('narticle:list')


      else:
          form = AuthenticationForm()

      return render(request, 'accounts/login.html',{'form': form})
```

my base layout is:

```
 {% load static from staticfiles %}


 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Narticle</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'styles.css'%}">
   </head>
   <body>
 <div class="wrapper">
   <h1> <a href="{% url 'narticle:list' %}">narticle </a> </h1>

   {% block content %}
   {% endblock %}
 </div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

the template for login is:

```
 {% extends 'base_layout.html'%}


 {%block content%}
  <h1> log in</h1>

  <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

    <input type="submit" name="log_in" value="login">

  </form>


 {% endblock %}
```

these are my base urls:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url, include
 from django.contrib import admin
 from. import views
 from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
 from django.conf.urls.static import static
 from django.conf import settings


 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^accounts/', include ('accounts.urls')),
     url(r'^narticle/', include ('narticle.urls')),
     url(r'^about/$', views.about),
     url(r'^$',views.homepage),

 ]
 urlpatterns+= staticfiles_urlpatterns()

 urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings. 
 MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 5):

Believe it's because you missed the underscore:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from.import views

 # app_name not appname
 app_name= 'accounts'


 urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_view, name= "signup"),
   url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name = "login" ),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed namespace in project urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^accounts/', include ('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
     url(r'^narticle/', include ('narticle.urls')),
     url(r'^about/$', views.about),
     url(r'^$',views.homepage),

 ]
```

Comment: Or if you have no access to add app_name=.. into incuded urls, then in modern Django versions you should do: url(r'^accounts/', include(('accounts.urls', 'accounts'), namespace='accounts'))  ---ie. include account.urls as if they have app_name 'accounts'.

Answer (score 0):

you should add namespace both on narticle/ and accounts/ url cause you certainly gonna have errors later let's see how to set it bellow:

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^accounts/', include ('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
     url(r'^narticle/', include ('narticle.urls',namespace='narticle')),
     url(r'^about/$', views.about),
     url(r'^$',views.homepage),

 ]
```